# Parsing EXI using C++

Tags: c++, c, xml, exi

I am in need of something for use with C++ which will parse EXI formatted messages. I am not picky in regards to the form of the solution. This could be a Xerces-like library, a rapidxml-like set of headers, or even a offline "compiler" which takes in the XSD file and creates C/C++ sources based on the contents.

What this *cannot* be is any form of Java solution. I have come across EXIficient and OpenEXI and both are Java based solutions and are not suitable for my situation. I am working in an embedded environment where we won't have the "*luxury*" of a JVM.

Comment: http://exip.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not many EXI parsers available.

You could try using the commercial but stable:
http://www.agiledelta.com/product_efx-me.html

Or the EXIP is also good, but in alpha stage:
http://exip.sourceforge.net/

Based on your implementation specs, your mileage with these apps may vary.

Comment: Thanks! I think EXIP will have to be what I end up using. Paying for something like this is not really an option. Since we are doing simple EXI stuff I think EXIP is "stable enough" for now.

Comment: exip is good but facing difficulties while parsing schema based input files.. Can you get me some examples if it supports. there are some example files in exip package but not very helpful.